# How to open a URL with AppleScript only if no other URL checked is the right one?

Tags: applescript

I'm looking for solution but my searches was not good so far

This is my code

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    if it is running then
        repeat with t in tabs of windows
            tell t
                if URL starts with "https://keep.google.com/" then
                    delay 1
                    activate
                else
                    open location "https://keep.google.com/"
                    delay 1
                    activate
                end if
            end tell
        end repeat
    else
        activate
        open location "https://keep.google.com/"
        delay 1
        activate
    end if
end tell
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
return ""
```

I'm able to check the URL, but for each URL that is not Google Keep I open a new URL. So if I have Gmail, Youtube and Keep opened, I open more two keeps URLs. **How to open only if no one is the right URL?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `tell application "Google Chrome"` in the following *code* snippet at the start of your *code block* will launch Google Chrome if it's not running.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    if it is running then
```

So, technically that's not the proper way to use the `running` *property* in the next line because as you presently have it coded, Google Chrome is always running when `if it is running then` is processed.

Here is an example of how I'd rewrite your *code* to make proper use of the `running` *property* and only open the target URL is it not already open.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
set theURLsList to {}
set theURL to "https://keep.google.com/"

if running of application "Google Chrome" then
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        repeat with t in tabs of windows
            copy URL of t to end of theURLsList
        end repeat
        if theURLsList does not contain theURL then
            open location theURL
            activate
        end if
    end tell
else
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        open location theURL
        activate
    end tell
end if
```

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not employ any *error handling* and is meant only to show one of many ways to accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.

Comment: Work like a charm, one question if I'm already looking for the chrome and the url is already open how change the screen to see the url? Is not party of the main question, I just realise now.